# Implement visitor count with Firebase Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, counter

Trying to implement a basic visitor counter that should increment whenever users click on a post. My method properly does that but the problem is counter increments whenever the same user clicks so it should happen only once. I have tried to handle this with booleans but did not work. Can anyone help please?

The counter part of my code.

```java
private void incredmentCount(){
        boolean isCounting = true;
        if (isCounting){
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("posts").child(postId);

            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

            hashMap.put("counter", counter++);
            myRef.updateChildren(hashMap);
            //stop counting as soon as database updates.
            isCounting = false;
        }
        

    }
```

Comment: "I have tried to handle this with booleans but did not work" Can you edit your question to show what you tried with those booleans?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done. what is possibly wrong?

Comment: What isn't working about the boolean `isCounting` in your code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the boolean isCounting should stop user from increment the counter over and over again. it should only increment once.

Answer (score 0):

Since `isCounting` is a local variable, it gets initialized to `boolean isCounting = true;` each time you call `incredmentCount`.

If you want to keep the value across calls, you'll need to move the variable out of `incredmentCount`, for example make it a field in the class.

If you want it to stay saved across program runs, you could store it in [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).